# What is the point of a FrameLayout for single element

Tags: android

I understand the advantage of a FrameLayout when you need to add multiple children to it. But what is the point of adding a FrameLayout as your root element when you only have one child (lets say a TextView)? I mean why wouldn't you simply set that single child (e.g. the TextView) as the root of your layout?

Comment: Use it for a background panel. For example, `CardView` is a `FrameLayout` with a specific background for the rounded-rectangle-with-drop-shadow look.

Comment: Could be a good reason, but I've seen people putting a single view in a `FrameLayout` without background customization, instead of simply setting the view as root.

Comment: Using a **FrameLayout** lets you stack views over each other. That said, you could use your **TextView** as the root layout, but any other view which contains that layout would have to handle it's layout options instead of the **FrameLayout** handling your contained **TextView** for you

Comment: *I've seen people putting a single view in a FrameLayout without background customization* - I understand that it sounds unnecessary but oversimplification will not have that much difference in terms of benefits. Enough overthinking that part ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `FrameLayout` is - as the name implies - a `Layout`. It inherits from `ViewGroup` which is used for **positioning** and **aligning** child views.

Of course you would be able to set a `TextView` alone in your Layout xml. But what are you going to do if you want it to be centered?

Then it would make sense to use a `FrameLayout` as a sort of "Wrapper" around your `TextView` which lets you position it the way you want.